# Why did i get this problem? It gets space char twice but i did not enter compiler that

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fak(int);
int main()
{
  int num;
  printf("ENTER A NUMBER:");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  fak(num);


}

void fak(int num)
{
int i=num;

for(;i>=0;i--)
{
    char a;
    printf("ENTER A CHAR:");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    if('A'<=a&&a<='Z'||'a'<=a&&a<='z')
        printf("%c IS A CHAR.",a);
    else if (a>='0' && a<='9')`enter code here`
        printf("%c IS A INT.",a);
    else
        printf("%c SPECIAL CHAR",a);
```

[When i run this code i am getting this fault. It gets space char twice but i did not enter compiler that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBKgW.png)

What should i do?

Comment: `scanf("%c",&a);` -> `scanf(" %c",&a);` Put a space before `%c`.

Comment: Unrelated, but `"%c IS A INT."` is a wrong assertion. It is a digit in that case. Same about "`CHAR`". It is not `char` but a "letter" or "alphabetic character". Check out the standard [classification routines](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha)

Comment: You should post text as text rather than an image, for one thing

Comment: Yeah it solved when i used space before %c . But why? Should we use all scanf for do that?

Comment: The duplicate explains in detail which `scanf` formats do not automatically skip whitespace.